# How do I check current variables when running a project in RStudio?

Tags: r, debugging, shiny, rstudio

Is there a way to check currently set variables and their corresponding values when running a project in RStudio?

This is for debugging purposes and am seeking an alternative to the browser() command. The browser command does not always work it seems.

Comment: My favourite is `debug(some_function)`, which opens the same debugger as `browser()` whenever  `some_function` is called. You might want to read [this](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html) for some general debugging strategies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't necessarily say it's a debugging tool, and I honestly like working with `browser()`, but are you aware of the *environment* tab? Sound exactly like what you are describing. It's usually a tab in the pane alongside 'history', 'connections' and 'git' and lists e.g. variable names and values and allows you to inspect them.